# using colsplit function for many columns

Tags: r

I have a matrix 500 row , 1000 cols. every col has 4 elements between them comma, I need to remove the comma.

the data looks like that.

```
     1            2          3          4    ...  1000
1  12,1,20   14,15,12    10,10,20    1,0,10 ... 1,5,3
2  12,1,20   14,15,12    10,10,20    1,0,10 ... 1,5,3
3  12,1,20   14,15,12    10,10,20    1,0,10 ... 1,5,3
.
.
500  12,1,20   14,15,12    10,10,20    1,0,10 ... 1,5,3
```

My code is

```
mat=matrix(data=NA, nrow=257, ncol=3)
n=1000
k=500
for(i in 1:n){
mat[i]<-colsplit(as.character(data[,i]), "," , c("a","b","c")) 
}
```

Not working, there is missing in my loop.
Could anyone help me to figure it out, Thanks

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example of `data` together with the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create new columns based on `,` as delimiter

```
library(data.table)
library(splitstackshape)

df1 <- cSplit(df, 1:ncol(df), sep=",")[,lapply(.SD, as.numeric)]
df1
#    X1_1 X1_2 X1_3 X2_1 X2_2 X2_3 X3_1 X3_2 X3_3 X4_1 X4_2 X4_3
#1:   12    1   20   14   15   12   10   10   20    1    0   10
#2:   12    1   20   14   15   12   10   10   20    1    0   10
#3:   12    1   20   14   15   12   10   10   20    1    0   10
```

Or use `cSplit_f` which would be faster for rectangular data (based on comments from the author of `splitstackshape` package (@Ananda Mahto)

```
 cSplit_f(df, 1:ncol(df), sep=",")[,lapply(.SD, as.numeric)]

str(df1)
#   Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  12 variables:
#  $ X1_1: num  12 12 12
#  $ X1_2: num  1 1 1
#  $ X1_3: num  20 20 20
#  $ X2_1: num  14 14 14
#  $ X2_2: num  15 15 15
#  $ X2_3: num  12 12 12
#  $ X3_1: num  10 10 10
#  $ X3_2: num  10 10 10
#  $ X3_3: num  20 20 20
#  $ X4_1: num  1 1 1
#  $ X4_2: num  0 0 0
#  $ X4_3: num  10 10 10
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(X1 = c("12,1,20", "12,1,20", "12,1,20"), X2 = c("14,15,12", 
 "14,15,12", "14,15,12"), X3 = c("10,10,20", "10,10,20", "10,10,20"
 ), X4 = c("1,0,10", "1,0,10", "1,0,10")), .Names = c("X1", "X2", 
 "X3", "X4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3"
))
```

Comment: No need for all the Github stuff--the package is on CRAN. Also, if the data are rectangular (which it sounds like it is) `cSplit_f` is faster. +1 though :-)

Comment: @Ananda Thanks, for the `cSplit_f`.  It is new for me.